# How do OAuth access tokens work for API requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth, omniauth

I've created a custom OAuth provider using [oauth-plugin](https://github.com/pelle/oauth-plugin). I'd like to create a provider API that gives access to user data, but I'm not sure how to properly construct the API query.

I've noticed that several Omniauth strategies, including [Twitter](https://github.com/arunagw/omniauth-twitter/blob/master/lib/omniauth/strategies/twitter.rb#L32), [Linkedin](https://github.com/skorks/omniauth-linkedin/blob/master/lib/omniauth/strategies/linkedin.rb#L38), and [Vimeo](https://github.com/lomography/omniauth-vimeo/blob/master/lib/omniauth/strategies/vimeo.rb#L35), access user data from their respective APIs via `access_token.get`, but these calls to the API seem to be generic, rather than specific to a particular user.

Does something within the `access_token.get`call identify the user to the API? If not, how is the user discerned?

Comment: Curious why this would warrant a downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 3-legged OAuth, the access token identifies and belongs to the user.

I wrote a blog post for [using oauth-plugin with rails to create an OAuth provider](http://blog.gazler.com/blog/2012/01/08/oauth2-provider-with-rails/).

If you follow my tutorial and use `oauthenticate :interactive=>false` to protect your API, then you will have access to the current_user method which will allow you to treat the user as if they are logged in.

You can read the formal spec at https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-23  Section 4 is related to authentication and is fairly readable.

Comment: `oauthenticate :interactive=>false` is precisely what I've been looking for, since it enables my API controller action to access the logged in `current_user`. Additionally, I was able to get everything working without explicitly defining `current_user` in the application controller as you did in your blog post. I believe this is because Devise has a built-in convenience method, but it might be version dependent.

Comment: @zeantsoi Thanks for pointing that out!  I'll check it out when I get some time.